# Why is my PowerShell script writing blank lines to console?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a bit of an odd problem. Or maybe not so odd. I had to implement a "custom clean" for a PowerShell script developed for building some unique configurations for my current project (the whys are not particularly important). Basically it copies a bunch of files from the release directories into some temporary directories with this code:

```
$Paths = Get-ChildItem $ProjectPath -recurse |
         Where-Object { ($_.PSIsContainer -eq $true) -and
         (Test-Path($_.Fullname + 'bin\release')) } |
         Select-Object Fullname

ForEach ($Path in $Paths)
{
     $CopyPath = $Path.Fullname + '\bin\Temp'
     $DeletePath = $Path.Fullname + '\bin\Release'
     New-Item -ItemType directory -path $CopyPath
     Copy-Item $DeletePath $CopyPath -recurse
     Remove-Item $DeletePath Recurse
}
```

And after the build copies it back with:

```
ForEach ($Path in $Paths)
{
    $CopiedPath = $Path.Fullname + '\bin\Temp\'
    $DeletedPath = $Path.Fullname + '\bin\Release\'
    $Files = Get-ChildItem $CopiedPath -recurse |
             where-object {-not $_PSIsContainer}
    ForEach ($File in $Files)
    {
        if(-not (Test-Path ($DeletedPath+$File.Name)))
        {
            Copy-Item $File.Fullname ($DeletedPath+$File.Name)
        }
    }
    Remove-Item $CopyPath -recurse -force
}
```

This is pretty clunky and noobish (Sorry, I'm a PowerShell noob drinking from a fire hose), but it works for the purpose and I will clean it up later. However, when it executes the initial copy to the temp directories, it writes a lot of blank lines to the screen, which isn't ideal as I have a message I display while this process is executing to assure our CM doesn't freak out and think it broke, but this message is blown away by the blank lines. Do you know what might be causing this and how I might solve this? I'm using PowerShell 2.0 out of the box and due to the nature of this project I can't upgrade or get any outside libraries. Thanks guys.

Comment: `New-Item` returns details of the new item that was created. Perhaps you could wrap that in `[void](New-Item -ItemType directory -path $CopyPath)` which would ignore the returned data but still create the folder. Although that shouldnt account for blank lines. FYI you are not doing any test for preexisting items. I would recommend things like `Test-Path` before you make new items or copy to prevent errors. It's also good coding!

Comment: I'd agree with @Matt that you either need to prefix `New-Item` with `[void]` or pipe it to `Out-Null`. As for testing for existing paths, since you are deleting your paths after use I don't really see the point of testing for existing paths.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician While it is unlikely `New-Item -ItemType directory -path $CopyPath` would fail if it already existed. The script should still continue on without it though.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I thought I was testing all of my paths, but I missed that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the only thing you're looking to do is clean up the console output, then all you need to do is use the pipeline. You can start the command with [void], which will exclude all information from the pipeline. You can also pipe the whole thing into the Out-Null cmdlet, which will trap all output, except for the lines that don't have output.

The New-Item cmdlet by default returns output to the console on my version of Windows PowerShell (4.0). This may not be true on previous versions, but I think it is... Remove-Item also doesn't return any output, usually. If I were to take a stab, I'd kill output on those lines that use the "Item" noun using one of the methods mentioned above.